# Update sql table

Tags: c#, .net, ado

I need to update sql table, i.e. if I have in table spicific record I want to update the record if record dosen't exist I  need to add it to the table.
How can I implemet it ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried getting data from db and if no such record exists, do an insert and the update otherwise. You have to try to post the code you tried so we can guide better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add columns, with some values. You need to use alter query with default constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE {TABLENAME} 
ADD {COLUMNNAME} {TYPE} {NULL|NOT NULL} 
CONSTRAINT {CONSTRAINT_NAME} DEFAULT {DEFAULT_VALUE}
```

Or if you want to check that a record or row is available in data or not and if not you want to insert that row then you need `if not exist`:

```
 IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM emp WHERE fruits = 'mango')
    INSERT INTO emp (fruits) VALUES ('mango')
```

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to add columns to its record when he says  _if the record doesn't exists I need to add it to the table_

Comment: Yes!! OP was not clear in putting details, so I added both possibilities. and I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update a record in the database you need to get the UniqueID of the record in the table.
To do this For instance if you are going to update your personal info

```
Select ID, LastName, FirstName, DateofBirth from PersonalTable
```

If you get dataset
get the ID in Viewstate

```
UPDATE PersonalTable SET (LastName,FirstName,DateofBirth) = '" + xyz + "', '" + yzx + "', " + 01/01/2013 + " WHERE id= Viewstate("ID")
```

if you dont get use the insert query

Happy Coding